# How can I find a substring in multiple files?

Tags: ruby, file

I need to use Ruby to go over directory and look for text in specific type files.

For example, I have folder with these files: *a.txt, b.txt, c.trr, d.trr*
and I want my code to check only *c.trr* and *d.trr* files and find if one of them contains the string "aaa".

I tried some options but non of them seems to work for me.

I tried:

```
Dir.foreach("/myusername/Desktop/a") do |fname|
    if  (File.extname(fname) == ".trr")
       begin
        fname.each_line do |line|
       if 
        line.scan(Regexp.new('aaa'))
        puts "found it!"
       else
        puts "no can do sir"
        end
        end
        rescue Exception => ex
                puts ex
        end
    end
end
```

Didn't work.
and when I tried to print `line` variable I got as a response the name of the file and not the lines in it.

I tried to change the `scan` function to `match`, and I also tried to 
change `Regexp.new('aaa')` to `\aaa\`.

Non of them seems to work. 
Does `Dir.foreach` also opens the file? If it is not, how can I open it? 
I tried to use `File.open(fname)` but I got the following exception:

> No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Comment: Try `File.open(File.join('/myusername/Desktop/a', fname))`

Comment: Unfortunately, It is still not working. And when I printing "line" I still see the name of the file and not the lines. There might be something wrong with fname.each_line

Comment: Of course. You call `each_line` on the opened file (which you get from File.open), not on the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the `Dir` methods will return to you just the filename. You'll still need to open and read the file manually.

```
Dir["*.trr"].each do |fname|
  content = File.read(fname)
  if content =~ /aaa/
    puts "found it in: #{fname}"
  else
    puts "not found in: #{fname}"
  end
end
```

You could use `Dir#[]` and pass the matching string, instead of using `foreach`. Then it's just a matter of comparing the file content against whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is excellent, but you can go even a step further in using Ruby's Enumerable processing by creating arrays of those containing and not matching the regex:

```
with_aaa, without_aaa = Dir["*.trr"].partition do |filename|
  File.read(filename) =~ /aaa/
end
```

...or, if you don't care about the ones *not* matching the regex, you can use `select` instead of `partition`:

```
with_aaa = Dir["*.trr"].select do |filename|
  File.read(filename) =~ /aaa/
end
```

Comment: Interesting! Not sure if this is a good solution in my case, but I will defiantly mark it for other uses in the future. Thanks!